# Sending user's information from back end spring-boot to front end issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I have been trying for 4 days to find a method that helps with sending the authenticated user's ID from back end (spring-boot) to front end (angular) but with no result .

So i decided to open a question about it, and i hope i get some help here .

I'm working with The JWT + spring security Only , i'm not using Auth2 in authentication , i wonder if i can use the TokenEnhancer method in my case to reach my goal, is it possible ? if No what can i do to reach what i want ?

I'm not able to find exemple with JWT token .. even in github ..

PS : my file securityConfig is extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

Any help about this ? i appreciate it  .

Answer (score 0):

I think using a cookie with secure flag could be a good idea.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
        cookie.setSecure(isSecure);
        cookie.setHttpOnly(isHttpOnly);
        cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        httpServletResponse.addCookie(cookie);
```